# mathematical opération with pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I have a structure in rdd that contains a record time like this :  02:00:30.
I want to convert the data from this format to the second format, i want to do this treatement: 02 * 3600 + 00 * 60 + 30 
could someone please help me to do this treatment in pyspark ?? thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please check this link first http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

map it

```
rdd=rdd.map(lambda row: [3600*int(row[0].split(':')[0])+60*int(row[0].split(':')[1])+*int(row[0].split(':')[2]))
```